# Android Shadow Más grande TextView

Tags: android, text

Tengo el siguiente código.

```
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="10"
    android:text="Text Shadow Example1"
    android:textColor="#FBFBFB"
    android:textStyle="bold"
```

pero no consigo ahcer una sombra más grande, por más que he jugado con  `android:shadowRadius` desde 0 a 50 o 500 no he conseguido el resultado que quiero, quiero se extienda mucho más la sombra, como por ejemplo en html cuando se le agrega blur,  o en photoshop que se aumenta la distancia de la sombra, pero en android no consigo más que un borde al texto muy pequeño y fino.

es posible en android? o con alguna librería?

Adjunto una imagen , el primer `textView` es el que consigo con `Android`.

El segund es el efecto que quiero conseguir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias

Comment: Puedes agregar una captura de como se ve la sombra.

Comment: espero mi respuesta te ayude :)

Comment: Hola @AndresBlend como cargas el Texto, como imagen?

Comment: no, como un textView en un ListView

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ingresar los valores en `float`  , intenta con esto

```
android:shadowDx="5.0"
    android:shadowDy="5.0"
    android:shadowRadius="10.0"
    android:shadowColor="#ff0000"
    android:text="Text Shadow Example1"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textStyle="bold"
```

Puedes revisar la documentación aquí: [TextView - shadow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:shadowRadius)

Comment: no :( no logro el efecto que busco, mira https://imgur.com/G7sJUft

Comment: pero ya corriste la aplicación? o estás solo desde el diseñador

Comment: si, desde el emulador de adnroid

Comment: cambiale el valor a android:shadowDx="0.0"
    android:shadowDy="0.0" , pone  5.0

Comment: nada, será que es el emulador =( , ya me ando descargando otro a ver https://imgur.com/wG36uP1

Comment: me funciona bien a mi, no te olvides del  android:shadowColor="@color/red"